# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Callbacks.OnConsoleLogHandler' to 'Kotlin.Jvm.Functions.IFunction2'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I created a binding library, via a `.arr` file.

And in one of the methods I need to pass a callback.

What I was trying to do:

this is my delegate:

```
public class Callbacks
        {
            public delegate void OnConsoleLogHandler(string message, Sometype type);
        }
```

this is my `Configuration` class:

```
public class Configuration
    {
        
        public Callbacks.OnConsoleLogHandler onConsoleLog;

        public Configuration()
        {

        }

        public Configuration(Action<Configuration> action)
        {
            var config = new Configuration();
            action?.Invoke(config);

            onConsoleLog = config.onConsoleLog;
        }
    }
```

here's how I'm trying to call a native method:

```
public static void Start(Configuration configuration)
       {
            var onConsoleLog  = configuration.onConsoleLog;

            Package.Name.Configuration config = new Package.Name.Configuration();                
            config.SetOnConsoleLog(onConsoleLog);
       }
```

But on this row `config.SetOnConsoleLog(onConsoleLog);`
I get error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Callbacks.OnConsoleLogHandler' to 'Kotlin.Jvm.Functions.IFunction2'
```

If I try something like this:

```
config.SetOnConsoleLog(() => { });
```

I get:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IFunction2' because it is not a delegate type
```

How can I put the delegate as a callback? Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try to define a event for this delegate `OnConsoleLogHandler`. And then register the callback for this event.

Comment: @doubletalk, did you ever resolve this? I'm getting a similar issue and I'm not sure what to do.